# Access: Single Line Form that Enters Data into Multiple Tables

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am creating a database that stores information about various applications used in a business. One of the attributes of an application is the databases that it depends on (database dependencies). I have a table for this information that has several fields that are foreign keys to other tables:

- Main Table: DatabaseDependencies

Fields:

- DatabaseID (Autonumber Primary Key)
- Server Name (Foreign Key from ServerNames table)
- Instance (FK from DatabaseInstance table)
- Database Name (FK from DatabaseNames table)
- and several others that are not relevant here...

ServerNames, DatabaseInstance, DatabaseNames have only two columns, the autonumber PK and the relevant string.

I want to create a form that has Comboboxes where the user can enter the data for a given database and then save the strings to the proper tables, while also saving the PK's autogenerated by those tables in the proper places in the main table (if the given server name, instance name, etc does not yet exist) or select from the correct entry from the existing server names, etc if it has already been entered.

I have created databases before in SQL Server but I always used C# and Entity Framework to set up the relationships, so I am new to Access but not to database concepts.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this here: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-27.html using the Not In List Event and some VBA code, specifically the code segment in Option 1, where I just had to replace the given table and field names with the ones from my database.